# Can a shiur Torah prolong the 72 minute wait to bentch?

Tags: bentching

After completing a meal a person has 72 minutes (according to some opinions) to bentch. Once this time has passed he lost his opportunity.

Say that during a meal the rav gives a shiur or you're in the middle of listening to an mp3 shiur or a video shiur, does that prolong the 72 minutes?

This shailah comes up when the rav gives a shiur in shul during seduah shelishit on Shabbat.

Comment: Why do you suggest that would make a difference?

Comment: Daniel I believe Torah has a din of food sometimes - for example you can be yotzeh seduah shelishit with divrey Torah bedieved.

Comment: I believe the halacha is based on how long it takes to digest the meal. So if the shiur slows down your digestive processes, you're in luck. (Also, I don't think that leniency of using *divrei torah* to fulfill *shalosh seudos* is widely accepted halachically.)

Comment: @Loewian, I believe it is only utilized when shabbat falls on erev pesach.

Comment: Please edit that bit into your question